# Unable to launch application in tmux

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, tmux, osx-yosemite

I get this error when I try to launch Sublime Text or SourceTree from tmux:

```
$ subl
Unable to launch Sublime Text 2

$ stree
Unable to open SourceTree
```

It seems that I can't open os x apps either:

```
$ open MPlayerX.app
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/MPlayerX.app.
```

I'm using Yosemite OS X 10.10 (14A388a), iTerm 2 with zsh, tmux 1.0a. Had the same problem using bash. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Not just a tmux problem for me. Same in bash and zsh/oh-my-zsh. It worked

Answer (score 16):

**Update:** This is procedure is unnecessary with tmux >= [v2.6](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/CHANGES#L80-L81)

I found a [post by Brendon Rapp](http://www.economyofeffort.com/2013/07/29/reattach-to-user-namespace-the-fix-for-your-tmux-in-os-x-woes/) describing a solution that doesn't require lots of aliases.

```
$ brew install reattach-to-user-namespace
```

Add the following line to the end of your ~/.tmux.conf:

```
if-shell 'test "$(uname)" = "Darwin"' 'source ~/.tmux-osx.conf'
```

Create a file named ~/.tmux-osx.conf with the following contents:

```
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l bash"
```

- The above solution allows the same .tmux.conf file to work correctly under both Linux and OS X.  If you only use OS X, you can just add the 'default-command' option directly to your ~/.tmux.conf.
- If you use a shell other than bash, replace 'bash' with your shell after the '-l' switch.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with tmux and patched it with [reattatch-to-user-namespace](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) and shell aliases.

1. `$ brew install reattach-to-user-namespace`
2. `$ vi ~/.bash_aliases`

   ```
   alias subl='reattach-to-user-namespace subl'
   alias stree='reattach-to-user-namespace stree'
   alias open='reattach-to-user-namespace open'
   ```
3. `$ source ~/.bash_aliases`

Not elegant, but works.

Comment: According to the docs, just add this to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

`set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"`

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding this to my aliases didn't work for me if I wasn't already in a `tmux` session (i.e. it threw an error if I was just in a naked, `tmux`-less iTerm session).

If you want to only set up this alias when you're in a tmux session, try this instead:

```bsh
if [ "$TERM" = "screen" ] && [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then
  alias stree="reattach-to-user-namespace stree"
fi
```

You may need to `echo $TERM` inside of a tmux session to see what your `$TERM` environment variable is set to. Mine was actually `screen-256color`, so I swapped out the value above appropriately.

Good luck!